# Как найти первообразный корень по модулю c#

Tags: c#

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать алгоритм на c#, который находит первообразный корень по некоторому модулю. Интересует алгоритм, который бы быстро работал с большими числами типа BigInteger (числа длиной более 128 бит). Нужно для реализации шифра. Нашла код (на C++), работает (но не знаю как для чисел BigInteger, хочу проверить, но нужно на C#), но не разобралась и не смогла переписать его на c# [смотрела тут](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/export_primitive_root). Помогите, пожалуйста, его переписать на c#.
**Код на с++**

```C++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Возведение a в степень b по модулю p
int powmod (long int a, long int b, long int p) {
    int res = 1;
    while (b)
        if (b & 1)
            res = int (res * 1ll * a % p),  --b;
        else
            a = int (a * 1ll * a % p),  b >>= 1;
    return res;
}

// Вычисление первообразного корня
// (Стандартный DFT использует комплексные числа, поэтому изменим алгоритм для работы в Zp)
// Ограничение: p - простое
int generator (long int p) {
    vector<int> fact;
    int phi = p-1,  n = phi;
    for (int i=2; i*i<=n; ++i)
        if (n % i == 0) {
            fact.push_back (i);
            while (n % i == 0)
                n /= i;
        }
    if (n > 1)
        fact.push_back (n);
 
    for (int res=2; res<=p; ++res) {
        bool ok = true;
        for (size_t i=0; i<fact.size() && ok; ++i)
            ok &= powmod (res, phi / fact[i], p) != 1;
        if (ok)  return res;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{ 
    
    int digit; 
    digit = generator(2002620789884339957);
    cout << digit;

    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Что вы уже написали на c#? Ну и стоит отметить, что данный алгоритм не очень-то подходит в чистом виде для больших чисел, так как он требует разложения N и phi(N) на простые, что делается (в данном случае) за корень от числа. Соответственно уже для 128-битных чисел факторизация просто подвесит комп на 30 лет.

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: @aepot не получается подобрать алгоритм нахождения первообразного корня для чисел типа BigInteger

Comment: С переводом этого кода на шарп что не получается? Вы хотя-бы для `long` попробовали? И что значит "подобрать"? Придумать?

Comment: @aepot с long работает, но это максимум, а мне нужно BigInteger, все же этот код не подойдет для этого... тк я не математик, то не знаю как оптимизировать этот год для больших чисел.

Comment: [Эффективные алгоритмы факторизации](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/export_factorization) на том же e-maxx. Больше вам вроде ничего не помешает. И все-таки добавьте то, что вы написали в код вопроса, иначе очень странно выглядит, когда вопрос про c#, а код на c++. Хотя алгоритм все еще достаточно тяжелый будет, даже с быстрой факторизацией. Максимум 200-битные, мне кажется, за адекватное время считать будет.

Comment: Немного поискал статьи на тему. В общем, значительных оптимизаций особо и нет. Подозреваю, что если вам нужно считать первообразные корни 1024-битных чисел, к примеру, то можете просто забить на это лет на десять, а там может получше ситуация будет.